# Deploying Jenkins Server on Google Cloud Run

Tags: jenkins, kubernetes, containers, serverless, google-cloud-run

Deploying Jenkins Server on Google Cloud Run

> **Cloud run service URL is long-awaited and the Jenkins server is not getting ready to configure**
>
> **Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready - waiting long**
>
> **but not being starting or getting ready**

[image: Cloud run service URL is long-awaited and the Jenkins server is not getting ready to configure]

Jenkins server is successfully running in my machine via Kubernetes pod
I want to run Jenkins server on serverless solutions, one of the best serverless is cloud run.

I have deployed **jenkins/jenkins:lts** container on **cloud run** and make it **public IP** to access cloud run service.
everything is working fine.

When I access public URL to configure Jenkins server it showing "Please wait while Jenkins is getting ready"

It is taking too much time and not getting ready. I have tried many times to delete service and check it locally, fine, and again deploy to cloud run, many times and it not getting ready, now it's stuck. Is there any way out to run Jenkins on the Google cloud run.

**Docker Image** jenkins/jenkins:lts

**Tag Image** gcr.io/projectName/jenkinsci:latest

successfully deploy on Google cloud run

but **Jenkins server is not getting ready**

Comment: While I could imagine a world in which this would work, you need a lot to get there. Notably you would need to write a jenkins executor cloud plugin to spawn jobs on cloud run as well.

Comment: You don't have any errors in the logs? You don't have to add additional configuration? No database? use authentication?

Comment: There might be **a lot of reasons** why Jenkins is not working out of the box on Cloud Run. Please learn how to debug containers by looking at logs, and maybe try running it yourself locally on Docker to see if Jenkins is capable of running standalone in a stateless environment. https://cloud.google.com/run/docs/testing/local

Comment: If you want serverless builds on Kubernetes, I would consider using Tekton instead https://github.com/tektoncd/pipeline